# Segmenting pandas dataframe with lists as elements

Tags: python, clustering, pandas, dataframe

I am working with a pandas DataFrame that contains a combination of numerical and categorical data on customer demographics and preferences. Each row contains information about an individual customer. `df` has 5000 rows and 30 columns.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':list('mno'),
                    'col2':[['a','b'],['d'],['a','b','c','d']],
                    'col3':[1,2,3],
                    'col4':[[1,3,4],[5,6,7],[8,3]]})
df

   col1     col2              col3        col4
0   m    ['a', 'b']            1        [1, 3, 4]
1   n    ['d']                 2        [5, 6, 7]
2   o    ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']  3        [8, 3]
```

I am hoping to use [k-prototypes](https://github.com/nicodv/kmodes) to segment customers into distinct groupings since there is no ground truth on class labels and I have mixed data. However, I am unsure how to effectively analyze the columns that have lists of multiple values, e.g. `col2` and `col4`. I looked into one-hot encoding to break up those columns into multiple dummy columns, e.g. `pd.get_dummies`, but I'm concerned that creating a sparse matrix may negatively affect my results. Can anyone suggest a better way of handling this problem?

Comment: No, creating a sparse matrices won't be a negative for your problem, it's that's why they are made for, to save memory when you have lot.of zeros

Answer (score 1):

Are you concerned that a column might have too many values and that one hot encoding will produce features with less predictive power? In that case you could select a handful of the features for more prevalent class values and keep them as is, while combining the other features for rarer class values into one feature.